# Equivalent definiton of Lebesgue integrability, upper functions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have an equivalent definition of Lebesgue integrability from Apostols Mathematical Analysis. I would like to prove that it is equivalent to the ordinary definition of Lebesgue integrability. I begin with some definitions.

**Step-function**

A function $s(x)$ on a compact interval $[a,b]$ is a step function if there is a partition of the interval $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that $s(x)$ is constant on each open subinterval $(x_i,x_{i+1})$.

**Step-function on an interval I**

Let $I$ be an interval (unbounded, bounded, open, closed, halfopen). Then $s(x)$ is a step-function on $I$, if there is a compact subinterval $[a,b]\subset I$, such that $s(x)$ is a step-function on $[a,b]$ and $s(x)=0$ on $I \backslash[a,b] $.

**Integral of a step function**

We let $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be the partition of $[a,b]$ and assume that $s(x)=c_i$ on $(x_i,x_{i+1})$ then we define
$$\int_I s(x)dx =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_i(x_{i+1}-x_i).$$

**Upper function**
A function $f$ is called upper if there exists a sequence of step-functions $s_n$ such that
$$s_n\nearrow f,\text{ae on I},$$
and $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_I s_n(x) dx,$$
is finite. We define the integral of $f$ as the last limit. It can be shown that this definition is well-defined.

**Alternative definition of Lebesgue Integrable functions.**

An alternative definition of Lebesgue Integrable functions is that it is the difference of two upper functions. And we define the integral as the difference of the integrals of the upper functions. It can be shown that this definition is well-defined.

**My question**

Using the machinery of standard measure theory it is almost trivial to show that if a function $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable according to the alternative definition presented here, then it is Lebesgue-integrable according to the standard definition. But I am wondering about the opposite implication. **How do we show that if a function is Lebesgue-Integrable according to the standard definition, then it is also Lebesge-integrable according to the alternative definition presented here?** The problem is that we must construct the two upper functions?, and the sequence of step-functions?

Update:
Notice that we use step-functions in this definition, that is, functions that are constant on intervals. In the standard definition we use simple functions, these functions are only constant on measurable sets.

Comment: Write $f = f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+$ is the positive part of $f$ and $f^-$ is the negative part of $f$ (both are positive functions and both exist a.e.), then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if $\int f^+ < \infty$ and $\int f^- < \infty$, or equivalently $\int f^+ + \int f^- < \infty$. Since $\int f^+ < \infty$, you know that there exist step functions converging to $f$ pointwise a.e. and the integrals converge (this is how the Lebesgue integral of a positive function is constructed). Same for the negative part $f^-$. Thus $f^+$ and $f^-$ are actually upper functions. I *think* this does it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The problem is that the functions you meantion are what are called simple functions, not step functions. The are not necessarily constant on intervals, they are usually created by taking the interse image of intervals.

Comment: Right, but you can break the simple functions up into step functions. It's very messy though.

Comment: @Masacroso To me the standard definition is where you first start with positive simple(not step)-functions. Then you define the integral for positive function as a limit of increasing simple functions, then you create the monotone convergence theorem. Then you define the integral for function that take both positive and negative values using $f^+$ and $f^-$. The difference is that the standard-definition does not use step-functions, that is functions that are constant on intervals. It uses simple-functions, that is, functions where you take the inverse image of intervals.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't think it will quite work to do that. Because I do think there are positive functions that are lebesge integrable(in the standard sense, they have a finite lebesgue integral), but that are not upper funcitons.

Comment: @user394334: What you end up having is that if $f$ is integrable in the Lebesgue-Caratheodory measure theoretic method is that one then can approximate $f$ by step functions. Then one use dominated convergence in the way of Apostle. There are things that need to be workout, but that is the general idea.

Comment: @user394334: Use dominated convergence. That is the key part of any approach to Lebesgue integration.